# How can i design expendablelistview, recylerview(gridview) in single layout in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

Previously am designed expandablelistview and recyclerview inside ScrollView but i saw in stack overflow they said this is not good idea,never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view.Then how can i design this.
This is my previous code:

```
     <ScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ExpandableListView
         android:id="@+id/secPage_explist"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:groupIndicator="@null"
         android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/grid_recycler_template"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/oreser_item_seperator"
    />

        </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Please tell me any one.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate height of `Expandablelistview` and `RecyclerView` programatically and Remove Scrollview

here in below is class that caluclate height of expandable listview

```
public class Calculate_Height {

public static int calculateHeight_expandable(ExpandableListView list) {

    int height = 0;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = list.getExpandableListAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return 0;
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, list);
            groupItem.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            height += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (list.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                for (int j = 0; j <listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            list);
                    listItem.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec
                            .makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }
        }

        height += list.getDividerHeight() * (list.getCount() - 1);
        Log.i("height", "" + height);
        return height;
    }
 }
```

set height of expandalbelistview in oncreate activity

```
   expandable_myitem.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            expandable_myitem.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Calculate_Height.calculateHeight_expandable(expandable_myitem)));
        }
    });
```

---

```
  expandable_myitem.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new     ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            expandable_myitem.setLayoutParams(new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        Calculate_Height.calculateHeight_expandable(expandable_myitem)));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,how can i calculate for GridLayoutManager and Expandablelistview  programatically

Comment: I edited my answer . from that you can able to calculate height of your ExpandableListview programatically .. in the same way you can do for GridLayoutManager....if you stuck anywhere then let me know. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your support.It working only  when child items not visible.if child elements are visible it collapsed.

Comment: again i edit  my answer.. when you do collpase and expand calculate height and set

Comment: same result bro,this is ok i will fix it.What about GridLayoutManager  height,how can i caluculate please give me hint.Thank you

Comment: did you calculate height  onexpand and oncollpase method in oncreate?

Answer (score 0):

Remove scrollview & add weight to linear layout use weight for recycle view and listview as per your layout other wise use dynamic height code for manage screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,how can i calculate for GridLayoutManager and Expandablelistview programatically